# Discord.py variables in while loop don't update

Tags: python, discord.py

This bot is meant to exile a user from a certain channel by moving them to a random channel in the guild. For some reason my code gets stuck in a while loop and won't update any of the variables. Even if ExileStop is set to True by using the other command, it will still register as False. The channel variable, which is where the user is supposed to be right now, also doesn't update even if the user moves.

````
import discord
import random
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
client = discord.Client()
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%', intents=intents)

ExileStop = False

@bot.command()
async def exile_stop(ctx):
    global ExileStop
    ExileStop = True
    await ctx.send("Stopped")

@bot.command()
async def exile(ctx, user: discord.Member, exiled_from):
    global ExileStop
    ExileStop = False
        
    channel_list = ctx.guild.voice_channels
    for i in channel_list:
        if i.name == exiled_from:
            channel_list.remove(i)
    while ExileStop == False:
        print(exiled_from)
        channel = user.voice.channel.name
        print(channel)
        print(ExileStop)
        if channel == exiled_from:
            await user.move_to(random.choice(channel_list))
            await ctx.send('exiling')
            continue
        

bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))```
````

Comment: Are you quite sure its possible to handle another command ("exile_stop") before it has finished handling the previous command?

Comment: After the first iteration, in you move the user to another channel, you have a tight loop that never `await`s anything, so it may lock up your bot and prevent it from doing anything else (including responding to the command that's supposed to break the loop).

Comment: @Blckknght how might one loosen such a loop?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you expect the loop to do. If the `if` condition isn't met (as it probably won't be after the first move), all it does is `print` stuff. If you don't have anything else to do, maybe just delete the loop entirely and just do the move once unconditionally?

Comment: @Blckknght I want the loop to exile a user from a channel. i.e. if they move back to the exiled_from channel, the if statement will be met again.

Comment: @James: Ah, I see. In that case, you probably just want to `await` something like `asyncio.sleep(0)` so that you yield control to other code. You might have other issues, this is just one that I can recognize without much async or Discord library familiarity.

Comment: @Blckknght Not just `asyncio.sleep(0)`, but I would recommend actually sleeping some amount of time (say, 1 second). If you do this without waiting, you will hold up the rest of your code and trip lots of ratelimits.